# Find the eculidean distance betweens points in a 2d grid in an optimal way

Tags: python

Given a 2d grid and coordinates of airplanes, find several airplane that are in conflict with each other. An airplane is in conflict with each other if the horizontal distance between airplanes is within 200 meters . Return the total number of airplanes that are in conflict with each other.

**Notes**: Airplanes is a 2d list => [[1,2], [4,6]] representing x and y coordinates.

I wrote a simple program in python to find the euclidean distance between points of the airplanes:

```
def find_airplane_conflict(airplanes):
    
    count_conflict = 0

    for i in range (len(airplanes):
        for j in range(len(airplanes):
            if airplanes[i][0] != airplanes[j][0] and airplanes[i][1] != airplanes[j][1]:
                distance = sqrt(pow(airplanes[i][0]-airplanes[j][0],2) + pow(airplanes[i][1]-airplanes[j][1],2) 
                if distance <= 200:
                   count_conflict += 1

   return count_conflict
```

How can this be optimized from O(N^2) operation without using numpy.

**Edit:**
if the grid is a square area of 10000 and there are 1000 coordinates.
I am randomly generating the airplanes coordinates below:

```
def coordinates():
    return int(random.random() * 10000) 

airplane_coordinates = [[coordinates(), coordinates()] for i in range(1000)]
```

and passing the coordinates to the function find_airplane_conflict

Comment: You can map the positions of the points on a lattice where each square is 200x200 meters. That is of linear complexity. Than you only need to check the neighboring grid places. Which is constant complexity, so you get down to O(N).

Comment: @flabons the airplanes have to be 200m within each other to be in conflict. I'm a bit confused by what you mean by mapping the positions

Comment: The comment by @Christopher Peisert is just wrong. Look at my answer and you see a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take the grid which is of size N*M as described in the code

```py
import random
x_min,x_max=0,10000
y_min,y_max=0,10000
N =(x_max-x_min)//200+1

M =(y_max-y_min)//200+1

grid=[[[] for i in  range(M)] for j in range(N)]

def coordinates():
    return [int(random.random() * 10000),int(random.random() * 10000)] 

airplane_coordinates = [coordinates() for i in range(1000)]

def grid_coordinates(coor):
    return (coor[0]-x_min)//200,(coor[1]-y_min)//200

for i,p in enumerate(airplane_coordinates):
    g_x,g_y=grid_coordinates(p)
    grid[g_x][g_y].append(i)

def find_conflicts():
    counter=0
    for i,p in enumerate(airplane_coordinates):
        g_x,g_y=grid_coordinates(p)
        for i in range(-1,2):
            for j in range(-1,2):
                for index in grid[g_x+i][g_y+j]:
                    counter+=1

    print(counter)
find_conflicts()
```

Each cell of this grid now contains all the plane indeces which are in the respective 200x200 square. Subsequently you only need to check 9 cells for each plane.

**Edit:**
I rewrote the code now including the real data which is used and corrected some mistakes. Further I also implemented the function which ckhcks all relevant cells. This yields an average number of checks of 5000 instead of 1000000. And it just scales like O(N)

Comment: the grid size here is square area lets say a 1000 by 1000. The airplanes have coordinates within the grid provided as a 2d list as mentioned. But they are in conflict within 200m of each other. The above solutions you provided is a bit confusing and not sure if it solves the problem

Comment: @fablon the airplane coordinates is a 2d array and not 1 dimensional

Comment: @EI-01 Have you understood the approach or do you need further help?